Which Lebanese politicians, in the 2023-24 violence cycle, had called upon Hezbollah not to persist in attacking Israel from Lebanese soil?
Pretty much what the title says.  One can be shocked at the numbers of deaths in Lebanon, reported to be nearly 500 two days ago, and still note that Israeli towns have been been getting targeted for almost a year and that 60000 people had to be evacuated.
Many countries would not put up with that indefinitely - and Israel is not known for its pusillanimity and infinite patience, not even under less controversial war leadership than Netanyahu's -  and the Lebanese establishment must have known Hezbollah was eventually going to provoke an escalated response.
Since Hezbollah is not running Lebanon, and since it is drawn only from the Shiite components of Lebanese society, have non-Hezbollah/non-Shiite Lebanese politicians called on it to stand back/stand down?
I am mostly interested in statements before the last two weeks, as attacks from other countries are known to have a rallying effect in most case.
On the other hand, I know that in the more distant past, politicians had stated Lebanon was not ready for another war.  This Q really is more about the last 6 months or so, as violence persisted.  To put it another way:  it is one thing to muse in the abstract about the undesirability of Hezbollah starting another war, before Hezbollah is shooting.  It is another to call on Hezbollah to stop shooting when it has started to do so.

Gaza is another question entirely.  The rights, and wrongs, of Israeli actions in Gaza are not the rights, and wrongs, of Israeli action against Hezbollah.  It is also not about the rights and wrongs of Israeli treatment of the Palestinians.  Neither is this question supporting, or criticizing, the methods used by Israel to strike at Hezbollah, as of the time it was asked.
This question is exclusively asking about what Lebanese politicians said about the wisdom, to Lebanese interests, of attacking Israel.
If those politicians base their arguments on Gaza and/or Palestinians, sure, that is in the scope of the question.
see also:  ethnic/religious demographics of Lebanon in 2022

Just a point of context to add. Lebanon does not currently recognize Israel's statehood. In addition, it still considers itself at war with Israel.

I don't know it that is historically that exceptional in the region.  Many countries consider themselves at war with others and... stay studiously quiet.  Even Syria is more in control

Lebanon’s Political Forces Oppose a War with Israel.  This is dated Dec 20th, 2023 so kind of outside the scope of the question.  Note that for example, Walid Joumblatt, cited here as being against Hezbollah drawing Lebanon into war has since then changed tack and is now supportive of Hezbollah's resistance

Re. VTC, "aim to discredit"... How is this fundamentally different from asking about which US politicians opposed invading Iraq in 2003?

Can you explain the motivation for including the first part of your question (about most countries not putting up with that indefinitely etc)? It seems to me to be superfluous to the main portion of the question which is much more objective.

@user3390629 We can both agree that when Israel is involved, different people may hold very diverging opinions, yes?  What I am trying to say here is that, in most countries, the citizens would be expecting action from their govt if their territory had been getting shelled/rocketed from a neighbor over a long period of time.  Even South Korea, which is circumspect around the occasional bit of nastiness from North Korea, would probably see the citizens ask for action if attacks took place at scale over a long period of time.   This is not Israel "losing it" on the spur of the moment.

@ItalianPhilosopher It would be quite possible for a question about US politicians' opposition to the invasion of Iraq to be closed for the same reason, so I'm not sure what your point is. I think the reason people are VTC your particular question is that it contains a lot of material which is fairly obviously just pushing your own views and isn't germane to what public statements have been made by Lebanese politicians.

@CharlieEvans Oh, do be more specific about my "own views".  What is it that should be changed?  Or, should the whole question be ditched entirely?  It really is pretty simple you know:  "Shooting at a bigger neighbor with a bad temper doesn't seem a good idea.  Did anyone say so beforehand?"  I am pretty sure we've had who-was-for-Iraq-invasion questions and nobody bothers to dress them up in neutrality that invasion was not a bad idea when asking who was for/against.  Or am I insufficiently criticizing Israel in the way I am asking this question?  What are your concerns? be specific, pls.

@CharlieEvans Maybe it was a good idea and you need to write a frame shift answer.  Be my guest.

@ItalianPhilosopher You asked for an explanation of close votes, I gave one, take it or leave it. I'm certainly not going to waste my time by engaging in a tedious and futile discourse with you.

TLDR: I'm not a regular observer of Lebanese politics, but it seems to me by surveying the statements of a few most notorious politicians there that except Christian leaders everyone else's (Sunni, Druze, not-officially-Hezbollah Shia) is either turning a blind [rhetorical] eye to Hezbollah's doings and just blaming Israel for everything, and/or actively endorsing Hezbollah's "unified arena" vision of the conflict.

At least some Christian parties (not a negligible entity in Lebanon) have called for moves that are more or less similar to the US plan.

May 1, 2024. The leader of a main Christian political party in Lebanon blasted the Shiite militant group Hezbollah for opening a front with Israel to back up its ally Hamas, saying it has harmed Lebanon without making a dent in Israel’s crushing offensive in the Gaza Strip.
In an interview with The Associated Press on Tuesday night, Samir Geagea of the Lebanese Forces Party said Hezbollah should withdraw from areas along the border with Israel and the Lebanese army should deploy in all points where militants of the Iran-backed group have taken positions.
[...] “All the damage that could have happened in Gaza ... happened. What was the benefit of military operations that were launched from south Lebanon? Nothing,” Geagea said, pointing the the death toll and massive destruction in Lebanon’s border villages.

Not coincidentally, Christians in Lebanon have the highest level of faith in the US.
Even the leader of the FPM, which is a Christian party that was traditionally allied with Hezbollah, advanced some criticism (sometime around March):

"The main problem that arose recently was crossing the limits of defending Lebanon and getting involved in a conflict in which we cannot make decisions," FPM head Gebran Bassil said.

Nonetheless, at about the same time Bassil was making ouvertures to Hezbollah, for a renewed political alliance, but also blaming Hezbollah for the fracture:

According to him, it was Hezbollah that "left the agreement when it abandoned the principle of state-building, the partnership with the FPM, and broke the ceiling of protecting Lebanon."

But words (especially from an opposition party) don't stop missiles. And the Lebanese Armed forces, which enjoy a high level of popularity in Lebanon (see previous link) have done nothing. The present central government is more affiliated with Syria, IIRC.

(Sunni) PM Mikati has been quite more vague on this, e.g.

24 October 2023
Mikati paid a surprise trip to southern Lebanon on Tuesday, as Israel and the terror group — a key Hamas ally — continued to trade deadly cross-border fire, while Israel and its Western allies have repeatedly warned the group against an escalation.
[...] During his visit, the caretaker prime minister emphasized what he said was Lebanon’s commitment to UN Security Council Resolution 1701, which ended the 2006 Second Lebanon War. That resolution called for the demilitarization in southern Lebanon of all groups other than state security forces. [...]
“We came to the beloved south… to reaffirm peace-loving Lebanon’s respect for all legitimate international resolutions and its commitment to implementing” resolution 1701, Mikati said, according to a statement.

So, yeah, words about commitment to UN stuff. OTOH he's used far stronger terms in denouncing Israel:

“The continuing Israeli aggression on Lebanon is a war of extermination in every sense of the word and a destructive plan that aims to destroy Lebanese villages and towns,” Mikati told a cabinet meeting. He urged “the United Nations and the General Assembly and influential countries... to deter the (Israeli) aggression.”

Likewise, words about the "resistance doing its duty" that can easily be interpreted as moral support for Hezbollah.

“We are always advocates of peace, and our choice is the choice of peace and the implementation of UN Resolution 1701. It is incumbent upon Israel to cease its repeated attacks on Lebanon and halt the war in Gaza, with everyone adhering to UN Resolution 2735,” Mikati stated.
He continued: “The resistance is doing its duty, and the Lebanese government is doing its duty, and our goal is to protect the country in every sense of the word.”

As another Christian politician (Samy
Gemayel) put it though, as long as the Sunnis don't take a stronger stance against Hezbollah, any concrete [Lebanese] efforts against it are likely to turn into sectarian warfare. (And even if the Sunnis did take a stronger rhetorical stance, it's IMHO not a given that Hezbollah can be convinced by words, but we don't really know unless/until that happens.)

Alas the Druze in Lebanon (or at least their most famous politicians) don't seem too inclined to blame Hezbollah for anything, e.g. in late July:

Lebanese Druze leader Walid Jumblatt warned Saturday about Israel’s efforts to “incite strife” in the region after it accused Hezbollah of being involved in the shelling of the town of Druze in Majdal Shams in the occupied Golan Heights.
Jumblatt said in light of Hezbollah’s statement denying any involvement in the attack on Druze, “We reiterate our warning and alertness to what the Israeli enemy has long been working on—to incite strife, fragment the region, and target its components,” as reported by Lebanon’s National News Agency. “We have previously thwarted this (Israeli) scheme, and now that it has reemerged, we remain vigilant alongside the resistance and all fighters confronting Israeli aggression and occupation.”

And about the situation in general, he said:

The armistice agreement dictates that Lebanon and Israel have a certain neutral distance in northern Lebanon as well as Palestine. But implementing the armistice agreement from one side is not logical.

That's pretty close to endorsing Nasrallah's "unity of the arenas".
As for the officially-not-Hezbollah, but still Shiite politicians, like the the Speaker of Parliament, Nabih Berri--don't look for any calls for Hezbollah to disengage there. He was recently (August) praising the wise plans of revenge of the Iran axis, with talk like "revenge is a dish best served cold" etc. He struck a more conciliatory tone recently, after Israel struck back on a large scale.
Or look at his earlier (April) interview in a London paper blaming (just) "Israeli aggression" for "turning most villages and towns situated south of the Litani river into dilapidated and uninhabitable areas" with no mention of any Hezbollah activities.

Almost half of the Syrian refugees in Lebanon are in Shiite areas, BTW. They are less welcomed in the rest. Geagea even asks for them to go back right now.

An interview with a Western affiliated news outlet isn't the vehicle for such to make this case, because it is not reaching out to the Lebanese people.  It is in the Lebanese press and the Lebanese parliament.

@ItalianPhilosopher: those will be in Arabic, so someone else who's fluent in that language can perhaps satisfy your curiosity.

Well, Western press coverage of what Lebanese politicians were saying to the Lebanese people would do just fine.  Mind you, I upvoted this in any case.

@ItalianPhilosopher Lebanon is a small country, of little import to the West. Except for the declarations of a few top politicians like the PM and (ahem) Nasrallah few get any foreign press coverage. L'Orient is a local (liberal) paper that publishes in English and French, but you can only read a few articles before the paywall kicks in.

@ItalianPhilosopher: there's a 40-min interview with Geagea in Arabic here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMiYGVYU_x8 apparently that was on LBCI which is a Lebanese TV Channel. It's in Arabic buy you may have some luck with YouTube CC auto-translation. Still you might complain that I in LBCI stands for "International".

What is meant by the statement "Christians in Lebanon have the highest level of faith in the US"? Are they in the US, or in Lebanon?

@ConnieMnemonic "faith in the US", not "highest... in the US".

Ahah, understanding has dawned, lmao. Thank you. @MaciejStachowski

I had the same misreading as @ConnieMnemonic at first, although I figured out what was meant after a second or third reading.  Very much feels like an unintentional garden path.
